# Electric field of a grounded cylinder capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I was given this question and am confused about the dynamics of the system.

> Consider this problem: a perfectly conductive tube with a radius $a$ and height $h$ is put into a conducting fluid with conductivity $σ$ at $t<0$, which is encased by a grounded cylinder.
> It is also known that at $t=0$ the electric density of the tube is $λ$.
>
> I am looking to find the electric field at every point in space at $t=0$.

My confusion comes here: There are 3 ways to analyse the system.

1. I can either look at the system as electrostatic (meaning the charges inside the conducting fluid and the grounded cylinder had no time to "rearrage") such that the field in space is caused only by the tube.
2. Another other way to look at the system is that the conducting fluid has infact not changed such that the field inside it is not necessarily 0, but the grounded cylinder causes the field outside to be 0 constantly.
3. The last way is when we allow both the conducting fluid and the grounded sphere to move charges such that the electric field at every point in space is E=0.

[image]

I am quite confused as to how I should approach these types of question and what intuition I should have coming into this problem, so any advice would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of example is similar to one in Griffiths Intro to Electrodynamics, 7.2.

Note 1: I wasn't sure if you actually need help solving the question given a certain option, so I included that too.

Note 2: I don't know if b is the radius of the outer cylinder or its diameter, but for simplicity I assume the former.

since the inner tube is perfectly conducting, it has a constant potential over its surface, call it $ V(a) $, similar to the outer tube having a potential of zero (in theory an equipotential if the outer tube is also a conductor. If this assumption is wrong, please lmk).

Anyway, this means that the difference in the potential has no dependence on where you are on the z axis (if the cylinders are parallel to the z axis). Consequently we shouldn't have any z dependence in the electric field solutions either. Then its safe to apply the usual field of a uniformly-charged cylinder equation, $$ E = \frac{\lambda(t) }{2\pi e_0 s } \hat s $$ where s is the radial cylindrical coordinate.

At time t=0, I'm guessing there's no charge leakage yet, so you should probably go with option 1.

so there's still an amount $ \lambda $ on the rod, so we can actually just say $$ E = \frac{\lambda }{2\pi \epsilon_0 } ln(a/b)$$

If you do end up wanting it for a particular value of $ I $, then it'll influence your electric field since it'll pick out a value of $ V(b) - V(a) $ which consequently will pick out a value of the electric field and how much charge is on the rod.

as a note on the choice of options, I doubt that you would want a steady state solution (option 3) as an answer instead. If this were the case, it would mean the charges immigrate fast enough that the current dies roughly at t=0. That would probably mean that this is just a thick tube instead of two tubes separated by something of finite conductivity.

as a note on option 2, I don't think you need to worry about what the field outside is since we have cylindrical symmetry + Gauss's law.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer! This really helped a lot. Regarding your last sentence, I am trying to figure out the electric field outside the cylinder in order to quantify the potential energy of the system at t=0, which is an intergral of E^2 over the whole space.

Comment: if you want that addressed, I think it'll end up having zero electric field outside since @ t=0 its basically just a charged rod inside a grounded tube, and I think the grounded tube will redistribute charges nicely. I think also you could assume this by uniqueness/analogy to a grounded sphere holding a charge in the middle.

Comment: ok thanks a lot!